# Achieving conditional check in JSON schema

Tags: json

I have a JSON schema structure with a field as follows,

```
"fruitColor": {
  "id": "/fruitType",
  "type": "string",
  "title": "Fruit color schema.",
  "enum": [
    "YELLOW",
    "RED"]
}
```

There is another field in the schema like,

```
"fruits": {
  "id": "/fruits",
  "type": "string",
  "title": "Fruits schema",
  "enum": [
    "APPLE",
    "BANANA",
    "POMEGRANATE"]
}
```

How can i design this schema in such a way that when the user enters the fruitColor as `RED`, he/she should be allowed to choose either `APPLE` or `POMEGRANATE` and in case of `YELLOW` the choice `BANANA` should be allowed. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: where shall the user provide inputs?

Comment: I'm performing JSON schema validation. When the user fail to comply with the schema provided by me I'll be throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Make the 2nd element, or `red`, of the key `enum` a dictionary with a value being a list containing `apple` and `pomegranate`. Do the same thing for the key `"YELLOW"`

#### Like so:

```
    "fruitColor": {
      "id": "/fruitType",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Fruit color schema.",
      "enum": [
        "YELLOW": "BANANA",
        "RED": ["apple", "pomegranate"]
         ]
    }
```

Comment: How do i acheive this dictionary structure in enum ? It is not getting recognized as a valid JSON.